# Mathematical description of the curve of a straight line in optics

Tags: optics, geometry

If you look at a square object from far away, all the edges look perfectly flat, but if the square is something like 2 feet by 2 feet, for example, and you get close enough to it, you can see that the edges all curve due to perspective. If you align your face with the center of it, the top edge curves downward on the left and right side, and the bottom edge curves upward on the left and right side. The closest term I can find to this is 'barrel distortion', although I'm not 100% sure that is exactly the concept I'm referring to.

Is there any sort of function or equation which describes the shape of this curve? I'm sure there must be, but my googling hasn't brought me anything.

I'm not sure what the appropriate tags for this question are, apologies. I asked this on the Math stackexchange but I didn't get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

["Barrel distortion" and its opposite "pincushion distortion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29) are unwanted lens errors. A "perfect" lens projects a straight line as a straight line, the same way a pinhole camera would do.

In the idealized high-school-level model of optics, there is no such distortion. But this model only fits thin glass elements, when compared with the focal length, or small angles. With thicker elements and wider angles it's increasingly difficult to find a design that focuses on the film/sensor plane and also shows little distortion.

As the surfaces of lens elements are rotationally symmetric around the center axis, so is the amount of distortion. It is a function of the angle between the object and the center axis of the lens.

As lens producers invest a lot of effort into minimizing the distortion, the remaining distortion can only be described with quite complex formulas that differ from lens to lens as well as with lens settings like distance and focal length. So, you can't describe it with one generic formula applying to all lenses.

Comment: Okay, there isn't one formula for all lenses, that's fair enough, but is there a formula that describes the curvature produced by Human eyes? I can see the curvature of edges in my every-day experience, and I'm thinking that might be a relatively consistent across the majority of humans.

Comment: To me, when I look at the corner of a square, its edges appear straight. When I look at a different place, the edges are still straight, only with a different angle. Only when I move my focus slowly along one edge, the continuous change of angle produces the impression of a curvature.

Comment: I'm in an office with a rather long rectangular panel of fiber glass. I can place my head about center height of it a couple feet away, and the panel extends to the left and right in my peripheral. I might be mistaken, because I find it really hard to accurately assess what's in my peripheral, but I definitely feel like it appears smaller as it extends to my peripheral, and it appears largest at it's closest point to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's the field of distortion wave aberration (geometrical point-spread function), optical imaging

Reference:
[Lecture notes](https://www.iap.uni-jena.de/iapmedia/de/Lecture/Imaging+and+aberration+theory1367359200/IAT_Imaging+and+aberration+Theory+Lecture+7+Coma+and+Distortion.pdf)